# Eigenvector of corresponding eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can we prove that for a one eigenvalue ,we can get corresponding two or more eigenvectors which are not scalar multiplication of each other .

Comment: Hint: That only works if the corresponding Eigenspace has dimension $>1$. Then the answer is obvious, as an Eigenspace in fact is a vector space.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is your matrix and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, find the basis of the null space of $A-\lambda I$. If it has more than one vector, then you would have proved your claim.